# (STM32) Wrinting into flash with HAL_FLASH_PROGRAM does not work

Tags: embedded, stm32

I am trying to write on the flash memory of an STM32L476RG with the HAL_FLASH_Program function but it always returns an error.

```
static FLASH_EraseInitTypeDef EraseInitStruct;
uint32_t PAGEError;
uint32_t Address = 0x080FFF10;
uint64_t data = 5;

/* Unlock the Flash to enable the flash control register access *************/
HAL_FLASH_Unlock();

/* Erase the user Flash area*/

/* Fill EraseInit structure*/
EraseInitStruct.TypeErase   = FLASH_TYPEERASE_PAGES;
EraseInitStruct.Page = Address;
EraseInitStruct.NbPages = 1;

if (HAL_FLASHEx_Erase(&EraseInitStruct, &PAGEError) != HAL_OK)
{
    /*Error occurred while page erase.*/
    HAL_FLASH_GetError ();
}

/*Write into flash*/
HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_DOUBLEWORD, 0x1FFF7000, data);
if (status== HAL_OK)
{
    printf("it works\n\r");
}
else
{
    /* Error occurred while writing data in Flash memory*/
    HAL_FLASH_GetError();
}

HAL_FLASH_Lock();
```

I tried to find wthe flash error code with the HAL_FLASH_GetError() function.
The error code I get is "168" (0xa8 in Hex) and I have no idea to what it corresponds.

My questions :

- What error is the code 168 (0xa8 in Hex)
- what do i need to change so that HAL_FLASH_Program works properly

Comment: Are you unlocking the flash? Are you erasing the flash? You'll definitely need to do the first, and you'll probably need to do the second (unless it was already erased).

Comment: yes, i do unlock the flash and erase the page where i want to write, then i lock the flash again. And even if i try to write into a "blank" space i doesn't work

Comment: Where is the code executed from? Generally when writing flash drivers, you can't execute the code from the same flash bank as you are programming. Because that's kind of the same thing as trying to lift the stone you are currently standing on - it ain't gonna work.

Comment: I don't know- I know that i can't write at the beginning of the flash otherwise it overwrites the intructions so i purposly chose an address not in that page.
How can I check this?

Also i updated the code

Comment: `HAL_FLASHEx_Erase()` expects a page number in `EraseInitStruct`, not an address. I see that even though you check the return codes from the HAL functions, you carry on regardless, even if there was an error.

Comment: You're also not setting `EraseInitStruct.Banks` to anything. It will default to zero (since your structure is static), but the address you are trying to erase is in flash bank 1 I believe.

Comment: @travellingMadness Check the flash manual, it should mention these things. If you are lucky there's more than one bank, in which case one easy work-around is to create two (or more) identical functions and place them in separate banks. Then the driver checks which bank to program and call the appropriate function. On some MCUs you can also execute the flash driver out of eeprom or data flash, if the MMU and other hardware allows it. And as a last resort, you could execute the code from RAM, by uploading it there temporarily.

Comment: Let us know what you changed, and whoever suggested it can post an answer that you could accept.

Comment: I changed the address to 0x080FF800. Created a variable uint32_t page_nb = 255. Set EraseInitStruct.Banks to FLASH_BANK_2 and EraseInitStruct.Page to page_nb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how the fields in `EraseInitStruct` are being set. The HAL driver for some STM32 parts expects an address. However, the HAL library for the STM32L476 expects a *page number*.

```
typedef struct
{
  uint32_t TypeErase;   /*!< Mass erase or page erase.
                             This parameter can be a value of @ref FLASH_Type_Erase */
  uint32_t Banks;       /*!< Select bank to erase.
                             This parameter must be a value of @ref FLASH_Banks
                             (FLASH_BANK_BOTH should be used only for mass erase) */
  uint32_t Page;        /*!< Initial Flash page to erase when page erase is disabled
                             This parameter must be a value between 0 and (max number of pages in the bank - 1)
                             (eg : 255 for 1MB dual bank) */
  uint32_t NbPages;     /*!< Number of pages to be erased.
                             This parameter must be a value between 1 and (max number of pages in the bank - value of initial page)*/
} FLASH_EraseInitTypeDef;
```

So you need to set the page number correctly, and also specify which flash bank you are trying to erase:

```
    EraseInitStruct.Banks = FLASH_BANK_2;
    EraseInitStruct.Page = 255u;
```

It is good practice to check the result of all HAL function calls, and abort the operation if there is an error.

@Lundin brought up a good point about possibly being unable to erase / program the flash bank that you are running code from. This is an issue for some devices, but the [reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0351-stm32l47xxx-stm32l48xxx-stm32l49xxx-and-stm32l4axxx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) for the STM32L476 (in section 3.3.5) says this is ok:

> ... during a program/erase operation to the Flash memory, any attempt to read the same Flash memory bank will stall the bus. The read operation will proceed correctly once the program/erase operation has completed.